# Why is the sum of all the elements in a subgroup generated by $10$ of $\Bbb Z_p$ is divisible by $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Consider the subgroup $\langle 10\rangle $ of  $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Let the order of the subgroup $\langle 10\rangle $ be $d$.

So $$\langle 10\rangle= \left\{10, 10^2, 10^3, \dots, 10^{d-1}, 10^{d} = 1\right \}.$$

Now is it true that sum of all the digits of $\langle 10\rangle $ is divisible by $p$? If so, then how is it true.

I have verified the same for $p=13$ where order of $10$ modulo $13$ is $6$. We have $$10+10^2+10^3+10^4+10^5+1 = 111111$$ and $$13 \times 8547 = 111111.$$

I am not able to see how this can be proved. Kindly help me out.

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

Let $\langle 10\rangle $ be a subgroup of $\Bbb Z_p$ with ${\rm ord}(\langle 10\rangle) = n$ Thus if $x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots x_n$ are the elements of the subgroup $\langle 10\rangle $ then $x_{i}^n \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ where $1 \le i \le n$. So, $x_i$'s are the $n^{th}$ roots of unity modulo $p$.

So, $x^n-1 = (x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)\dots(x-x_{n-1})(x-x_n)$.
Now the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ in $x^n-1$ is $0$. So $x_1+x_2+x_3+\dots+x_{n-1}+x_n \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ **This is where I am confused**. How can I write $x_1+x_2+x_3+\dots+x_{n-1}+x_n \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ ? For this to be true I must have $x^n-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. Right?

So, the sum of $x_i$'s which are the elements of $\langle 10\rangle $ is congruent to $0$ modulo $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your difficulty is that the problem contains a red herring: This is true for *any* subgroup of $(\Bbb{Z}/(p))^*$ other than the identity subgroup $<1>$. The easiest way to see this is to remember that any subgroup is cyclic and thus is generated by a root of unity.  Thus, if $\xi_1,...,\xi_n$ ($n>1$) are the elements of the subgroup, we have $x^n-1=(x-\xi_1)\cdot\cdot\cdot (x-\xi_n)$.  (We know this because each of the $\xi_i$ satisfy $\xi_i^n=1$, and as there are $n$ of them, they are precisely the $n$ roots of $x^n-1$.)  But the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ in this polynomial is both $0$ (since $n>1$) and also $-(\xi_1+\cdot\cdot\cdot +\xi_n)$.   Thus, the sum of the $\xi_i$ is $0$ in $(\Bbb{Z}/(p))$, i.e., it is divisible by $p$.

Note that this uses the well-known fact that $(\Bbb{Z}/(p))$ is a field.  Also, note that to solve your problem, you don't even need the fact that every multiplicative subgroup of a finite field is cyclic, since $<10>$ is obviously cyclic.

Comment: I am not able to see how this statement is true: If $\xi_1,...,\xi_n$ are the elements of the subgroup we have $x^n-1=(x-\xi_1)\cdot\cdot\cdot (x-\xi_n)$. Also, when you say "any subgroup is cyclic and thus is generated by a root of unity" How does this hold true. Could you provide some more information

Comment: @cabmetric I added the details on the first of those.  You don't actually need the other to answer your question, so I'll refer to you any abstract algebra text that introduces fields.  They will all give a proof that finite fields have cyclic multiplicative group.  As for "generated by a root of unity", well, $x^{p-1}=1$ for any element of $(\Bbb{Z}/(p))^*$, so they are all roots of unity.

Comment: This statement " so they are all roots of unity". Should it be  so they are all roots of unity modulo $p$ ?

Comment: Well, you could add that, but when you are working modulo $p$ in the first place, it is traditional not to bother.

Comment: I have updated the question stating the things that I have understood. Kindly have a look. If I am wrong then please correct me.

Comment: @cabmetric I think you meant "coefficient of $x^{n-1}$" where you wrote "coefficient of $x^n-1$".

Comment: @cabmetric Also, $x^n-1$ is not 0 mod p.  The point is that its second coefficient is 0, and that coefficient is congruent mod p to -1 times the sum of the roots

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122647/discussion-between-cabmetric-and-c-monsour).

Comment: I see mathjax doesn't work in chat.  Thanks, stackexchange...

Comment: What I am confused about is that how can we write $x_1+x_2+x_3+\dots+x_{n-1}+x_n \equiv 0 \ (mod \ p)$ Because $x_i$'s are the $n^{th}$ roots of unity modulo $p$. So we have to write $x^n-1 \equiv (x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)\dots(x-x_{n-1})(x-x_n) \ (mod \ p)$ ? Else how can we conclude that $x_1+x_2+x_3 +\dots +x_n \equiv 0 \ (mod \ p)$

Comment: Multiply out $(x-\xi_1)(x-\xi_2)\cdot\cdot\cdot (x-\xi_n)$. What's the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$?

Comment: The coefficient is $\xi_1+\xi_2+\xi_3+ \dots + \xi_n$ and since $x^n - 1 = (x-\xi_1)(x-\xi_2)\cdot\cdot\cdot (x-\xi_n)$ so $\xi_1+\xi_2+\xi_3+ \dots + \xi_n = 0$ But how can we write $\xi_1+\xi_2+\xi_3+ \dots + \xi_n \equiv 0 \ (mod \ p)$ from here ?
Also, why is this -----> $x^n-1 \equiv (x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)\dots(x-x_{n-1})(x-x_n) \ (mod \ p)$ not correct ?

Comment: The last statement is correct.  (It was only incorrect when you were adding that is was congruent to 0.)  The the previous statement *is* mod p.  (You are working in the field of p elements.)  It wouldn't even be true if it weren't mod p.

Comment: "$Z_p^*$ is a multiplicative subgroup of a finite field $Z_p$" Is this a correct statement ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a symmetry you can exploit!  Let $S$ be your sum.

If you multiply it by 10, you will get the same sum modulo $p$; the only effect is to permute the order in which powers of 10 appear.

This means that $10 S \equiv S \pmod{p}$, which is $9 S \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. If $p \neq 3$ this implies $S \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ which is what we wanted to show.

If $p=3$ the claim is false: $10 \equiv 1 \pmod{3} $ so its order is 1 and 1 is not divisible by 3.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  It's well known that the $n $-th roots of unity add up to zero,  because  $1+\xi+\dots+\xi^{n-1}=\dfrac {\xi^n-1}{\xi-1}=0$.   But the elements of $\mathbb Z_p^*$ *are* $p-1$- th roots of unity (by Lagrange).