# Sum of all the elements of the coset of a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

A while ago I posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4088820/why-is-the-sum-of-all-the-elements-in-a-subgroup-generated-by-10-of-bbb-z-p). I understood the case for the subgroup $\langle 10 \rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$. But, I think the same result holds for the cosets of the subgroup $\langle 10 \rangle$. So, my question is,

> Why is the sum of all the elements of a coset of the subgroup $\langle 10 \rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ is divisible by $p$ ?

Comment: That question seems to be in the group $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ under multiplication.  This one seems to be about the additive structure.  Which is it?

Comment: @Randall Multiplicative structure.

Comment: Then the "name" of the group should be changed to something standard like $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$, $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$ or $U(\mathbb{Z}_p)$.

Comment: What goes wrong when you try to use the same techniques that were used to solve the prior question?  After all, if $G$ is the subgroup and $hG$ the coset then the sum of the elements in $hG$ is just $h$ times the sum of the elements in $G$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a_1,\dots,a_k$ be the elements of a coset of the multiplicative group of $\mathbb Z_p$ of size other than $1$, assume the coset can be written as $a_1H$ where $H$ is a subgroup.

If we take all of the elements in the coset and multiply them by $h\in H$ with $h\neq 1$ we get the elements $a_1,\dots,a_k$ in a different order.

It follows $(a_1+ \dots + a_k) = h(a_1+ \dots + a_k)$, and so the sum is $0\bmod p$.

Comment: I didn't understand any of the step. Would you kindly explain more. Thanks !

Comment: well in the first step I just described the notation for our coset. In the second step I took $h$ and showed that $s=hs$ where $s$ is the sum of all the elements of the coset.

Comment: Maybe we can go step by step and see which one isn't understood.

Comment: Sorry, I got it now. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you have any questions feel free to ask me.

Answer (score 2):

I like Onir's answer better since it proves the result directly, but since you already understoond the answer to your previous question I will show how this result follows easily from that one.

Let $h_1, h_2, \ldots, h_n$ be the elements of the subgroup $H = \langle 10 \rangle$, with $h_1 = 1$. Following Onir's notation the elements $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ of $H$ are all of the form $a_1 = a_1h_1, a_2 = a_1h_2, \ldots, a_n = a_1h_n$.

Now $a_1 + \ldots + a_n = a_1h_1 + \ldots + a_1h_n = a_1(h_1 + \ldots + h_n)$.

From your previous question we know that $(h_1 + \ldots + h_n)$ is divisible by $p$, so it follows that $a_1 + \ldots + a_n = a_1(h_1 + \ldots + h_n)$ is divisible by $p$ as well.