# Prove that the number $1^k + 2^k + ... + 12^k$ is divisible by $13$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that the number $1^k + 2^k + ... + 12^k$ is divisible by $13$ for $k = 1, 2, ..., 11$.

My attempt:
If k is odd number, then $1^k +...+6^k +7^k ... + 12^k \equiv 1^k + ... + 6^k - 6^k - 5^k - ... -1^k \equiv 0 (mod 13)$.
But if k is even number then $2(1^k + ... + 6^k)$

Please give a good hint or explain clearly how to solve. Thanks you

Comment: You can use this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4146778/sum-of-all-the-elements-of-the-coset-of-a-subgroup/4146784#4146784

Comment: Hint: think about quadratic residues.

Comment: Let $r$ be a primive root $\bmod 13$.

Notice that $r^k\neq 1$,

now notice the sequence $1^k,2^k,\dots,12^k$ is a permutation of the sequence $r^k1^k,r^k2^k, \dots , r^k12^k$.

It follows $1^k + \dots + 12^k = r^k(1^k + \dots + 12^k)$ and so the sum must be $0\bmod 13$.

Comment: If you put $k=2t$ you get that the expression is equal to $2\cdot (1^t+3^t+4^t+(-4)^t+(-3)^t+(-1)^t)$ mod $13$ and argue again for $t$ odd/even given that $k$ is small that should be feasible.

Comment: If you prove by induction, account for the fact that is fails with $k=12$.

Comment: Thank everyone for your hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be specific: $2$ is a primitive root modulo $13$. Hence any number from $1$ to $12$ can be written uniquely as $2^n$, for some $n$ between $1$ and $12$. Hence after a rearrangement   your sum becomes:
$$2^k+ 2^{2k}+ \dots + 2^{12k} \pmod{13}.$$
If we denote your sum by $S$, then
$$ S \equiv \sum\limits_{n=1}^{12} 2^{nk} \pmod {13}.$$
Notice that the right hand sum is nothing but
$$ 2^k (2^{12k}-1) = 2^k (2^{12}-1)r.$$
Where $r$ is some integer. $2^{12}-1$ is divisible by $13$. Hence $S$ should be divisible by $13$.

Comment: +1. This generalizes by replacing 13 & 12 with p & p-1 for any odd prime p.

Comment: Not this specific method as 2 need not be a primitive root modulo every $p$, prime. Instead I can argue with a primitive root, say 'r'. Then our equation would be $$ S  \equiv \sum\limits _{n=1}^{p-1} r^{nk} (mod p), $$ where $S$ denotes the sum of $k$ powers of numbers from 1 to $p-1$. But the right hand side would be $$r^k\frac{(r^{(p-1)k}-1)}{r^k-1}$$. If we multiply both sides of the congruence by r^k-1 and then notice that the right hand side one is divisible by $p$, the left one should also be divisible by $p$. Since $p$ cannot divide $r^k -1$, it must divide $S$.

Comment: I should have said that "2" will (obviously) not work in general, but that there does exist a primitive root mod $p$. ( Arithmetic mod $p$ on $\Bbb Z$ is a finite field. If $F$ is a finite field then its multiplication, restricted to $F\setminus \{0\},$ is a $cyclic$ group.)