# Sum of the elements in a subgroup of $U(n)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let, $n$ be a composite number and $b$ be an element of order $d$ in $U(n)$. Then, sum of the elements of the subgroup $\langle b \rangle $ in $U(n)$ is divisible by $n$ and so is the sum of the elements of the coset of the subgroup. I have had questions similar to this, [Question 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4088820/why-is-the-sum-of-all-the-elements-in-a-subgroup-generated-by-10-of-bbb-z-p) and [Question 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4146778/sum-of-all-the-elements-of-the-coset-of-a-subgroup).

My attempt to this problem.

Let, $\langle b \rangle = \left\{g_1,g_2,g_3, \dots g_d\right\}$. Then each of $g_i$'s are the $d^{th}$ roots of unity modulo $n$. i.e. $g_i^d \equiv 1\pmod{n}$. As such, $x^d - 1 \equiv (x-g_1)(x-g_2)(x-g_3)\dots(x-g_d)\pmod{n}$. Now coefficient of $x^{d-1}$ is $0$. So, we must have $n \mid (g_1+g_2+g_3+\dots+g_d)$.

Again, consider any coset $c_k\langle b \rangle$ of $\langle b \rangle$ such that $c_k\langle b \rangle = \left \{m_1,m_2,m_3, \dots, m_d \right\}$. Then applying arguments similar to an answer to Question 2.

Let, $h$ be an element of $\langle b \rangle$ such that $h \neq 1$. Then, $h(m_1+m_2+m_3+ \dots + m_d) = (m_1+m_2+m_3+ \dots + m_d)$. Consequently, $n\mid (m_1+m_2+m_3+ \dots + m_d)$.

From which I have,

> Sum of the elements of the subgroup $\langle b \rangle $ in $U(n)$ is divisible by $n$ and so is the sum of the elements of the coset of the subgroup.

Are my arguments valid ? If not, then please correct them.

Thanks!

Comment: What about $n=8$, $b=3$, $1+3=4$ not divisible by $8$?

Comment: @DerekHolt I have this theory. Numbers $n$ for which the prime decomposition consist of primes for which $b$ have order $1$ in U(p), this result fails. Here, the prime decomposition of $8$ is $2^3$ and order of $3$ has order 1 in $U(2)$ whereupon the result fails. I have no idea if this holds. Is there any way to verify it ?

Comment: @DerekHolt If $n$ would have been a prime, the result would have been true. Right ? I mean, Sum of the elements of the subgroup $\langle b \rangle$ in $U(p)$ is divisible by $p$ and so is the elements of the coset of the subgroup.

Comment: @DerekHolt Where, do the arguments fail ?

Comment: I have given you a counterexample, so I don't need to read your attempted proof. If you apply the proof to the counterexample you should find out where it fails.